# Accept all incoming XMPP chats wokkel python

Tags: python, xmpp, chat, google-talk, wokkel

I have an XMPP client working with Google's GTalk XMPP server. I'd like to make it so that my JID/resource can receive messages from anyone (whether they are subscribed to me or not). Right now, if a client sends a messages to my username without being subscribed, Google's server returns a service-unavailable error (as it should).

```
<service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
```

But, I'd like to make it so that the message would go through. The use case here is to provide a public support chat entity so that users can chat me but I don't want them to be subscribed to all my activity (like status messages, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Talk explicitly blocks messages from entities you don't share presence with as a spam prevention measure. You can't turn that off, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yep I ended up having to write a relay bot